# Objective-C: autoreleased object as parameter for method

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

could the following code lead to problems?

```
- (void) method1 {
      NSMutableArray *myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

      ... fill the array

      [someObject someMethod:myArray]; // someObject does work on that array (without retain!)
}
```

A sometimes-appearing crash in my app looks like it IS a problem; but I would not understand that... shouldn't myArray stay alive at least until the end of method1?

Thanks a lot for your help!

So my questions besides "can that be a problem" are:
- would it be enough to remove autorelease and make a release at the end of the method?
- if not: do I have to make a retain/release in "someMethod"?

EDIT: but this can be a problem, am I right?

```
- (void) method1 {
      NSMutableArray *myArray = [self getArray];

      ... fill the array

      [someObject someMethod:myArray]; // someObject does work on that array (without retain!)
}

- (NSMutableArray) method2 {
      return [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Cocoa’s ownership rules specify that received objects should remain valid throughout the scope of the calling method unless you do one of the two following things: (1) remove an object from a collection or (2) dealloc a "parent object". See [Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000922)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume for a moment that you meant this to be `NSMutableArray` rather than `NSArray`. If you really mean `NSArray` here, then it is all impossible. You can't "fill the array" on an immutable array.

Yes, this should work. Your problem is likely elsewhere. A common mistake here would be over-releasing something you put into `myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a couple of open brackets on the line where you allocate your array. Should be `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: I generally like to use the easier (and shorter) `[NSMutableArray array];` rather than wrapping 3 calls. FWIW…

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely **correct**. Do not listen to people telling you to remove the autorelease and manually release the array after the call to `someMethod:`.

In 99% of cases using an autorelease'd object has *absolutely* no negative performance impact on your application. The only time you want to worry about it is in loops.

The `[[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease]` pattern is just the same as using a built-in helper method like `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`. They both return an autoreleased object, but you probably don't worry about performance with the latter. Again, only worry about autorelease in large loops, or when Instruments tells you you have a problem.

Using the `[[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease]` style also keeps all the memory management on a single line. If you get used to typing `[[[` you won't forget the release. If you are copying and pasting code, or moving code around, you won't accidentally lose the corresponding `release` because it's all on the same line.

It's also easier to review code that uses the `[[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease]` style because you don't have to go around hunting for the `release` further down the method to make sure the memory management is correct.

So in terms of readability and safety and correctness, your code is absolutely fine and good. This applies to both your original snippet and the follow up you added below. Performance of autorelease only becomes an issue when you have large loops.

Your crashing issue must be caused by some other factor that is not evident in the code you posted.

I also suggest you read the [Memory Management Programming Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) if you have not already. Basically, and autorelease'd object is guaranteed to remain valid until the enclosing pool is released. In your case, the autorelease pool exists higher up in the call stack (probably the main runloop) so you can be safe in the knowledge that your autorelease'd array will remain valid for the duration of any calls you make.

One last point. Your array allocation code could also make use of the `array` helper constructor:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This is even simpler, cleaner and shorter than your original.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Mike. But are you sure that the second code is 100% robust? Isn't it possible that the array I get from method2 is released somewhere in the "fill the array" part? Not very likely, but still, possible - isn't it?

Comment: As long as your code follows the ownership rules there's nothing that can go wrong. The array returned from method2/getArray is not going to be autoreleased until your code returns up the stack. If the 'fill the array' code performs a release on the array without having done a retain/copy/etc, then that is simply an error in your code and yes something can go wrong. But if all of your code is correct and you only release objects you have ownership of (i.e. objects you have alloc/retain/copy'd) then everything is good.

Answer (score -2):

Best thing to do will be something like that:

```
- (void) method1 {
      NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      ... fill the array

      [someObject someMethod:myArray]; // someObject does work on that array (without retain!)
      [myArray release];
}
```

and it's best from two different angles. One way you are holding your array till you have no need for it, so it will no wipe from memory until you say so. Second is the same sentence, only the reason is that you will clean up memory from no more needed objects as soon as it could be done.
The last may need some more explanation... Autoreleased objects should be autoreleased as soon as you have no need for it, but they are released on two basic rules: at the end of block(not always) or at the memory pressure after end of the block(yes always). In other words NSAutoreleasePool doesn't always release stuff at the end of some block of the code, and it's not even close to be rare that it delays those releases to later point.
Anyway you should always check for over-releasing your object as it will lead to crash when you'll try to reach such object at your code.

Comment: The main autorelease pool does in fact drain at the end of every run loop: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW5

Comment: That is true, however not every method is a run loop and so you CAN found yourself with a lot of memory used for stuff you have no need for a long time(in terms of program time not seconds or so) when you need it for some other stuff till it will be freed on the end of the current run loop